# Singleton pattern combined with Factory

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton, factory-pattern

I'm running an email marketing program that runs and schedules campaigns. So I have two types of campaigns in it:

1. Ad hoc
2. Scheduled

And since I want my program to create one campaign at a time. I think I'm going to need Singleton pattern. 
Each campaign has attributes that are common and attributes that are specific. E.g. Adhoc campaign does not need a time schedule. Also a scheduled campaign reads from a pre-written SQL file while ad hoc campaigns are run instantly.
I would like to have a well-structured design to support these. Is a combination of **Factory** and **Singleton** the answer?
If so, can I have a simplified example?
If not, what do you recommend?

Comment: I cann see the factory generating campaign objects. but why the singleton? which element do you want to exist only once in your program? are you trying to ensure each campaign is unique? if so, singleton is wrong here

Comment: @Dr.Elch About singleton, I don't want accidentally to fill two campaigns instead of one. So I want to make sure if the user is trying to run a campaign all the forms s/he'll fill goes into one campaign.

Comment: How do you decide which campaign to create?

Comment: @NedStoyanov At the beginning of the program the user can choose whether to create an ad hoc campaign or a scheduled campaign.

Answer (score 2):

Patterns are nice, but a pattern is a solution to a specific problem. You don't seem to have any of those specific problems.

From your requirements, you need a single variable of a base-type and an if-statement to put either one or another derived class into it.

If you want noodles, you have to decide if it should be spaghetti or tortellini. Pick one, heat, eat. Please don't build a NoodleHeatingAbstractFactory that only allows heating of a single, well guarded noodle dish. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

You typical use singletons when you want a global shared resource. To have one instance of something you don't necessarily need a singleton unless it is created from multiple locations, if not you can just create one instance and pass it around. I think AbstractFactory fits well here, but not sure about Singleton.

*Update*
If the user chooses which campaign to create I don't think you need a factory. Just create the appropriate campaign and you can store it in a ServiceLocator which is usually a Singleton or alternatively inject it into each Form/Window that you create.

The dependency injection Tends to be a it easier to unit test as you can mock the campaign

Comment: So how can I make sure every textbox or combo that the user fills in multiple steps of creating the campaign will be written on the same instance of the campaign?